# Count occurrences of a range in another range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given two lists/ranges, I'd like to have a single cell with the count of the first list items that match anything from the second list. For example:

List 1:

```
A
B
A
C
D
D
A
C
Z
```

and List 2:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

This should give `8` (since `Z` isn't in List 2). In this particular example I know I can use:

```
= COUNTIFS(List 1, 'A', ... , List 1, 'E')
```

but I need something that would scale if List 2 were really large. I tried:

```
= COUNTIF(List 1, List 2)
```

However I'm not sure what exactly it's doing since the number it returns is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(List1,List2,0))))
```

Where List1 is the range containing your first list, and List2 is a range containing your second list. Confirm as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter.